# Transfer QMessageBox setting to a separate class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've used QtDesigner to make ui files that I then use to make classes, like

```
class MyPopup1(MyBaseClass, MyClass):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyPopup1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        ...
```

Granted I used some tutorial for this so I'm not actually sure what all of that does. But now I have written code that generates a popup that uses the `QMessageBox` class and I would like to move this code to a separate class so I can call it from multiple places.

How do I move this code to make a `MyPopup2` class?

```
MyPopup2 = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(parent = self.central_widget)
MyPopup2.setWindowTitle("My Popup 2")
MyPopup2.setText("Some text")
MyPopup2.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Question)
MyPopup2.addButton("Btn1", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
MyPopup2.addButton("Btn2", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.ActionRole)
choice = MyPopup2.exec_()
```

I know I probably need to connect the button signals to functions and use `self.done()` to send the result back to a call.

I am mostly confused on what to put as `MyBaseClass` and `MyClass` for the second popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full solution for the example is

```
class MyPopup2(QtWidgets.QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NoMatch, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("My Popup 2")
        self.setText("Some text")
    self.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Question)
    self.Btn1 = self.addButton("Btn1", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
    self.Btn2 = self.addButton("Btn2", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.ActionRole)

    self.Btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.done(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.RejectRole))
    self.Btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.done(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.ActionRole))
```

Which can be called with `choice = MyPopup2.exec_()` from anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Qt Designer provides a class that serves to fill a widget, so a recommended way is to inherit a widget and inherit from the generated class of Qt Designer, for example the structure that Qt Designer provides has the following structure:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def setupUi(self, AAA):
        ...
        self.retranslateUi(AAA)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AAA)

    def retranslateUi(self, AAA):
        ...
```

Then depending on the template you should choose as MyBaseClass to QMainWindow, QDialog or QWidget and call `setupUi()` which is the method that you add the other widget to the window as you point out:

```
class MyPopup1(MyBaseClass, MyClass):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyPopup1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        ...
```

But in the case that you are going to create the widget, MyClass is not necessary, so in your case the solution is the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyPopup2(QtWidgets.QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyPopup2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Popup 2")
        self.setText("Some text")
        self.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Question)
        self.addButton("Btn1", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        self.addButton("Btn2", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.ActionRole)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    popup = MyPopup2()
    if popup.exec_() == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Accepted:
        print("Btn2")
    else:
        print("Btn1")
```